# Could not detect language for functions at functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, deployment, web-deployment, flutter-web

After firebase deploy in flutter web I get this error: [image: error]

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437098/firebase-deploy-error-could-not-detect-language-for-functions-at) person recommends firebase init, but I already have Firebase in the app.
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Can you add the contents of `package.json` from `functions` folder?

Comment: `{
  "dependencies": {
    "languagedetect": "^2.0.0"
  }
}`
@PeterKoltai

Comment: On Firebase Functions init, the `package.json` gets populated with settings like `engines`, dependencies for `firebase-functions` etc., do you have these as well?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I fixed it by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69372091/7856586)

Comment: @PeterKoltai How can I get this info from functions from my Firebase?

Comment: @PeterKoltai functions were written by hand and I don't use it in my flutter web app

Comment: If you want to use Firebase Functions, then you have to initialize it with `firebase init functions`, which creates `functions` folder with necessary files.

Comment: If you don't use, then you should not deploy functions.

Comment: (Funny thing here: you have `languagedetect` package, but the error message is not about this, but because it can't detect the programming language of functions.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across this issue with a custom build process and pointing only to my `dist` folder.

There are three requirements for a successful build:

1. a `firebase.json` with `functions.source` pointing to a directory containing a `package.json`
2. The `package.json` containing a `"main":"path-to-index.js"` field.
3. A node engine specified in either the `package.json` or `firebase.json`

```json
//firebase.json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "./some-dir"
  }
}
//some-dir/package.json
{
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for my Firebase monorepo custom deploy setup.